# Azure container registry (ACR) webhook to App Service gets 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

Here's what we know so far...

1. the team can successfully run the Azure DevOps pipeline, which deploys a Linux container to Azure container registry
2. we can successfully verify that the new container is deployed based on the timestamp

However, when the container registry webhook attempts to execute we get a 405 Method Not Allowed -

I am looking into things and have started wondering about the permissions to pull the image to the wep service. Is there an identity that I am missing? Do I need to create something that will have a “pull” role to deploy the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where you are pulling the image? Normally you need to assign the "AcrPull" role to a Managed Identity or Service Principal in order to be able to pull from ACR.